# Converting a datastore column from string to timestamp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have a datastore entity which has a column *name* `timestamp`. It was supposed to be a timestamp type but it is a `string` type as of now. Now, this column has values in 2 formats. `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ`, `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS-offset_hours`.

In our code, we are doing sorting on timestamp. Which is essentially sorting the "string". Now the question is, how can i convert this "string" column into "Timestamp".

Do i have to do any conversion for existing values which are in different format? How can i do it in terraform?

Answer (score 0):

Google datastore has no notion of schema migrations, you're going to have to write a taskqueue job to do it.

The proper way would be to create a new column called `timestamp_2` and backfill it. Here is an article GCP wrote:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema